# Selenium Apply button not working on combo box?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have problem with apply button. I have combo box filter and everything is fine, it is switching between squares.But when it suppose to do apply, somehow it just continue like it is not selected anything and test finishes successfully, but there is no filtering that I need.

Can someone check my code and part with inspector bug. Maybe I am missing something?

My Java code:

```
if (type.equals("")) {

elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + id + "_menu']//a[@class='FIText']"));

    if (elementList.size() > 0) {

        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + id + "_menu']//div[@class='CFApplyButtonContainer']//button[@class='tab-button']//span[@class='label'][text()='Apply']/..")).size() > 0) {

            type = "multi_checkbox_with_apply";
        }else {
            type = "multi_checkbox_without_apply";
       }
   }
}
```

Inspector bug:

```
<div class="CFApplyButtonConatiner" style="height: 21px;">
 <button class="tab-button tab-widget disabled" type="button" style="max-width: 56px" disabled="">
 <span class="icon"></span>
 <span class="label">Cancel</span>
</button>
 <button class="tab-button tab-widget focus disabled" type="button" style="max-width: 56px" disabled="">
 <span class="icon"></span>
 <span class="label">Apply</span>
</button>
```

Can someone check this please?
I don't have idea why it is not working? Maybe someone has idea how to test it.

BR,
Marija

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, this solution will look for element which is displayed and it will click on it!!

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.CFApplyButtonConatiner"))));
List<WebElement> elementsList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.CFApplyButtonConatiner > button");
for(WebElement  ele: elementsList) {
    if(ele.isDisplayed()) {
        ele.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used like Ranijth's suggestion:

```
    if (type.equals("")) {
        elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + id + "_menu']//a[@class='FIText']"));

        if (elementList.size() > 0) {


            //if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + id + "_menu']//div[@class='CFApplyButtonContainer']//button[@class='tab-button']//span[@class='label'][text()='Apply']/..")).size() > 0) {


                    if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.CFApplyButtonConatiner > button"))!=null) {

            //if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.CFApplyButtonConatiner > button")).size() > 0) {


            type = "multi_checkbox_with_apply";
            }
            else {
                type = "multi_checkbox_without_apply";
            }
        }
    }
```

And now it is working fine, but now I need to test it to check output. If someone have better solution, let me know.

Comment: if you think it's helpful pls give a thumbs up !!